# product list not showing on server , but working localhost magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, url-rewrite, core

i am using code :

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list_home.phtml"}}
```

this code file list_home.phtml:

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');

?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>

<div class="newproducts">



    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>

         <div class="carousel">
         <div class="slider">

    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>


            <div class="slide<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <?php include('view/labels.phtml')  ?>                   
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(210); ?>" width="210" height="210" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                <div id="productimgover<?php echo $_product->getId()?>" style="display: none;"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(64); ?>" width="64" height="64" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></div>
                <div class="new-description">
                    <div id='productname<?php echo $_product->getId()?>' style='display:none'><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></div>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>                
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>

                                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>   

                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="new-bottom-description">
                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>              
            </div>

        <?php endforeach ?>

        </div>
        </div>
                        <?php if($_collectionSize > 4): ?>
            <div class="prev new-arrow">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="next new-arrow">&nbsp;</div>  
        <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($_collectionSize > 4): ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery('.carousel').iosSlider({
                desktopClickDrag: true,
                snapToChildren: true,
                infiniteSlider: false,
                navNextSelector: '.new-arrow.next',
                navPrevSelector: '.new-arrow.prev'
            });    
        </script>   
    <?php endif; ?>        

</div>


    <?php endif; ?>
```

**app path file : app\design\frontend\rwd\MYTHEME\template\catalog\product**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to `admin panel -> system -> permission -> blocks`

check there is block name is listed? if not then add this block name

```
catalog/product_list
```

and `is allowed` to `yes`

Comment: I think that's the right answer, but when I want a new build with  server error 500 :-o

Comment: did you upgrade the magetno version?

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/500-server-error-when-I-try-to-add-new-block-in-permissions/td-p/22988  check this for solution.

Comment: this working and thank you very much <3